# Using SPServices to retrieve InfoPath repeating section fields in a SharePoint 2007 Library?

Tags: infopath, spservices, library

I have an InfoPath 2007 form that contains a repeating section field.

I publish this form to SharePoint 2007, which create a Library.

How do I use SPServices to retrieve this field from the Library since it is a repeating section field that contains two text box, 1 list box, and 1 check box?

(If it is impossible, are there any Jquery Plugin for me to retrieve this repeating section field?)